# How to use or combine Data disks in linux ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd, minecraft

Last year I bought a dedicated server from OVH for my Minecraft server because many of the Minecraft server creators was suggesting that I move to a dedicated server instead of shared hosting. I bought one, and these are the specs:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | Intel i7-6700K (4c/8t - 4 GHz/4.2 GHz) |
| RAM | 32GB @ 2133 MHz |
| Storage | 2× 480GB SSD SATA 1× 4TB HDD SATA |

At that time, I ignored the data disks to focus on the RAM. As time went on, I learned about the `df -h` command and, when I checked I only saw 439GB on `/dev/md3/`, which is the root partition.

[image: Disk Free Output]

This doesn't seem right, though, because the server provider says that I have 2× 480GB SSDs and 1× 4TB HDD:

[image: CLICK FOR IMAGE]

This is the result of lsblk
[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAUGF.png)

My question is: how do I use the other 480GB SSD and also how do I use the 4TB HDD? Is it possible to combine the two 480GB SSD into the root?

Comment: Looking at the output, I would venture a guess that your two SSDs are configured in RAID0 and your 4TB disk is not formatted for use, so invisible to the file system. Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk` and `sudo disk -l`? This will show information about your disks and partitions.

Comment: sure sure! and it's done. Thanks for the reply